# Disable keyboard input on Android TimePicker

Tags: android

I'm developing and Android app using the 1.6 SDK. I'm using a `TimePicker` and I don't want the soft keyboard to come up when you click on the digits in the `TimePicker`. I only want the `TimePicker` to be changed using the plus and minus buttons. I've tried using `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` hoping those would do it, but they didn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

try to use:

```
myTimePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

to disable focus on the text views of the internal NumberPickers

Comment: This also works for DatePicker, just use DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS instead.

Comment: Just use ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS.. They all have the same value - __ - '

Comment: You also can use                     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 in xml.

Answer (score 23):

Add this in your XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Defines the relationship between the ViewGroup and its descendants when looking for a View to take focus.

Comment: This answer should get more upvotes as it solves the problem in xml itself

Answer (score 4):

XML:

```
<NumberPicker
    ...
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this works for TimePicker, but I found the correct paramter to use to prevent  the keyboard from displaying when focusing an edit text or using the copy and paste menu on its contents:

First, you should call `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` on the `editText`.

Next instantiate the InputTypeManager:

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

And then, call `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` on the `imm` object, but using the `InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` as second parameter instead of 0 (as advised in first answer):

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
```

This will prevent the soft keyboard from ever popping up when clicking/focusing this EditText control, even when using the menu key to perform copy/paste operations.

PS: if you want to prevent copy/paste operations you can call `editText.setEditable(false)` but then you won't be able to dynamically change the EditText's contents.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried (targeting 4.0.3)

```
myTimePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

with no success.  After searching google for "android TimePicker BLOCK_DESCENDANTS not working" i followed the hit

```
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38369
```

where the last post, which is by a "Project Member", states:

"Descendant focusability refers to a view's ability to take focus, as in focus traversal using a keyboard, trackball, or d-pad. It does not affect touch events by design.

If you need to block touch events from a descendant view, consider overriding onInterceptTouchEvent in a parent view and returning true when blocking touch events is desired. This will cause the MotionEvents to be sent to the intercepting parent until the last pointer goes up."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Please refer to this question as well:

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: This doesn't work for the TimePicker. I've done that before with an EditText. Also, I don't just want a way to hide the soft keyboard, but basically to make the EditTexts inside the TimePicker to never have focus. I only want the values to be changed using the plus and minus buttons, and I don't want the user to be able to click in the area where the numbers are and have a cursor come up. I've been trying to figure out how to get a reference to those children inside the TimePicker to do this...but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

This does *not* work either for EditText controls... If you press & hold the Menu key on an EditText on which you have set `InputType.TYPE_NULL` and called `immhideSoftInputFromWindow(...)`, the soft keyboard will still pop up along with the copy/paste menu options.

Comment: PS: this was referring to the previous post on the use of InputtMethodManager, sorry, I meant to use the "feedback" button !!