# Dolphin browser - how to not show keyboard on text box

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable keyboard input on Android TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391216/disable-keyboard-input-on-android-timepicker)

I have a Jquery UI datepicker on an input type=text element

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
```

...

```
<input type="text" id="date"/>
```

Using dolphin browser on android, selecting the datepicker pops up a keyboard (as well as showing the datepicker itself..)

How can I disable that and not show the keyboard?

Thanks

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391216/disable-keyboard-input-on-android-timepicker

Comment: @Dirty-flow Disagree. That question is about `android` development, whereas this is about web development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to achieve this.

Dolphin shows the keyboard if an input type=text element gets focus. (unbinding the focus event doesn't help)

So I remove focus from it when clicked:

```
$( "#date" ).click(function(event) 
{
    this.blur();
});
```